# Why approximate pairwise distances only over lower triangle of distance matrix?

Tags: data-mining

In the context of dimensionality reduction.

Why approximate pairwise distances only over lower triangle of distance matrix?

$$\min_{\{\hat{x_i}\}} I = \sum_{i <j} ({ \hat{ d_{ij} } - d_{ij} })^2$$

(also known as *raw stress*)

Where $d_{ij}$ are distances of original data points and $\hat{d_{ij}}$ contain new coordinates that would approximate pairwise distances.

(as my notes give)

Is it perhaps that the upper triangle is a duplicate of the lower, since surely $d_{ij}=d_{ji}$ ($i \not= j$)?

Answer (score 0):

$\require{cancel}$

You are right

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i,j} (\hat{d}_{ij} - d_{ij}) &=& \color{blue}{\sum_{i < j}(\hat{d}_{ij} - d_{ij})} + \color{red}{\sum_{i > j}(\hat{d}_{ij} - d_{ij})} + \color{orange}{\cancelto{0}{\sum_{i = j}(\hat{d}_{ij} - d_{ij})}} \\
&=& \color{blue}{\sum_{i < j}(\hat{d}_{ij} - d_{ji})} + \color{red}{\sum_{i > j}(\hat{d}_{ji} - d_{ji})} \\
&=& \color{blue}{\sum_{i < j}(\hat{d}_{ij} - d_{ji})} + \color{red}{\sum_{j < i}(\hat{d}_{ji} - d_{ji})} \\
&=& 2\color{blue}{\sum_{i < j}(\hat{d}_{ij} - d_{ji})}
\end{eqnarray}